# ImageChops in Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, image-processing

I was trying to install ImageChops on my Mac(OS Sierra) and I have python 3.6.
Whenever I do `pip3 install ImageChops` it gives me a message as :

***Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ImageChops (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for ImageChops.***

I have no clue how to proceed and I need ImageChops for working in Images.

Comment: How did you install Python3? Where? What is your PATH? How are you tryy to install ImageChops? Where?

Answer (score 0):

ImageChops is a module in the Pillow library. Use Pillow instead of PIL, since  PIL is not maintained anymore. Instead of `pip3 install ImageChops` it should be `pip3 install pillow`. To use the ImageChops module,

```
from PIL import ImageChops
```